# Different Colors for Google ColumnChart

Tags: javascript, php, google-visualization

I am trying to draw a graph with data coming from php code as an array passed on to the draw function. Colors show if I am using PieChart, but NOT ColumnChart. How can I get the bars to show different colors?

Here is my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("visualization", "1.1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(<?php 

    $baseText = '';
    $trimmedPercentbf = '';
$js_arraybf = "['Percentage','$baseText'],";

    $counter = 0;

    $getBasicFunctionality = [SQL Query Here];
        while ($basicFunctionality = dbfetch($getBasicFunctionality)):

            $baseTextbf = $basicFunctionality["sat_lower_level_text"];


    $weightsTotal = $basicFunctionality["total"];

            $average = $basicFunctionality["weightAVG"];
            $countTotal = $basicFunctionality["total_users"];

            $counter += $countTotal;

            $percentage = ($average)/5 * 100;
            $trimmedPercentbf = number_format($percentage, $decimals=2);




                    if($counter != $countTotal):
                        $sep = ",";
                    else:
                        $sep = ",";
                    endif;


                        $js_arraybf .= "[ '$baseTextbf', $trimmedPercentbf ]".$sep;


                endwhile;


                                    $js_array = rtrim($js_arraybf, ', ');

                print "[".$js_array."]";






    ?>);

    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('community'));
    chart.draw(data, {width: 800, height: 800, is3D: true,/*vAxis: {format:'#%'},pieHole: 0.4,*/colors: ['#242424','#437346','#97D95C','#7D252B','#EB9781','#FFD2B5','#4A4147','#3796c8', 'red','yellow','green', 'blue'],axisFontSize:12, title: '2.Leadership Management & Communication'});
  }
</script>
```

// The sample data that comes through from the php code as an array is as follows:
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([['Percentage',''],[ 'label1', 51.43 ],[ 'label2', 60.00 ],[ 'label3', 66.67 ],[ 'label4 ', 60.00 ],[ 'label5', 66.67 ],[ 'label7', 100.00 ],[ 'label8', 100.00 ],[ 'label9', 100.00 ],[ 'label10', 100.00 ],[ 'label11', 100.00 ],[ 'label12', 80.00 ],[ 'label13', 40.00 ]]);

//The current graph that has only one color is as follows:
[image: single color graph]

//I need the graph to look like the one below which I used jqbargraph, but cant use jq since it's causing layout issues with my long labels:
[image: multi color graph]

Comment: What do the resulting pie and bar charts look like? Can you share some dummy input data?

Comment: var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([['Percentage',''],[ 'label1', 51.43 ],[ 'label2', 60.00 ],[ 'label3', 66.67 ],[ 'label4 ', 60.00 ],[ 'label5', 66.67 ],[ 'label7', 100.00 ],[ 'label8', 100.00 ],[ 'label9', 100.00 ],[ 'label10', 100.00 ],[ 'label11', 100.00 ],[ 'label12', 80.00 ],[ 'label13', 40.00 ]]);

Comment: var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('community'));
        chart.draw(data, {width: 800, height: 800, is3D: true,vAxis: {format: '#\'%\''},/*pieHole: 0.4,*/colors: ['#242424','#437346','#97D95C','#7D252B','#EB9781','#FFD2B5','#4A4147','#3796c8', 'red','yellow','green', 'blue'],axisFontSize:12, title: '2.Leadership Management & Communication'});
      }

Comment: It would be best to update the question with this information and to add screenshots of the resulting images.

Comment: have updated the question as requested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The colors you have defined via the `colors`-option apply to columns.

When you want to set colors for rows as in your case you must do it via a style-column, e.g.:

```
var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Percentage', '',{ role: 'style' }],
    ['label1',  51.43, '#242424'],
    ['label2',  60.00, '#437346'],
    ['label3',  66.67, '#97D95C'],
    ['label4',  60.00, '#7D252B'],
    ['label5',  66.67, '#EB9781'],
    ['label7',  100.00,'#FFD2B5'],
    ['label8',  100.00,'#4A4147'],
    ['label9',  100.00,'#3796c8'],
    ['label10', 100.00,'red'],
    ['label11', 100.00,'yellow'],
    ['label12', 80.00, 'green'],
    ['label13', 40.00, 'blue']
]);
```

[**https://jsfiddle.net/qdaw7ssx/**](https://jsfiddle.net/qdaw7ssx/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer...but my problem is actually arising from the fact that I am picking the label values from a database table dynamically. They are passed into an array and then echoed as above (print "[".$js_array."]";) .The labels are not static. I hope you understand me?

Comment: When you want different colors for rows you must provide the the data as needed, so you'll need to modify the output of your PHP-Script

Comment: Okay thanks...but is there anything I am missing? If I simply change 'var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart' to 'var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart' , the colors are showing on the pie Chart, as is...why should it not work with ColumnChart?

Comment: It's like I said, the colors-option in a ColumnChart applies to Columns(series), not rows. A ColumnChart may have multiple data-columns, a PieChart only 1. The colors-option will not be ignored, but it will not work in the way you think. When you take a look at your first screenshot you'll notice that the bars are not blue(it's the default bar-color). They are colored in #242424 ....that's the first color from your color-option. When you would have more data-columns(series) the other colors also would have an effect: https://jsfiddle.net/qdaw7ssx/9/